# Size and position of an element in a text widget

Tags: css, height, centering, contact-form-7

I have trouble centering and modifying the height of a contact form inserted in a text widget positionned in the left footer of my website.

http://www.durocketdescarottes.fr/

I'd like to reduce the height of my form and center it horizontally.

I have tried this CSS snippet :

```html
/* Contact form customization */
.wpcf7{
   height: 20%;
   max-width: 50%;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Changing the max-width property does change the width of the form, but I am unable to center it in the widget area using the usual "margin: auto;" trick.

Changing the height property does not do anything.

EDIT: following D_S_B suggestion, I tried to style the div.wpcf7, but my changes don't appear in the CSS style of my page. What is going on ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at your css, it looks like there are styles applied to div.wpcf7, as well as the styles you posted from .wpcf7.

[image: styles inspector]

The classes applied do the div.wpcf7 are more specific than the ones without the div selector, so any margin you apply to your class will be overwritten by the margin: 0 applied to the div.wpcf7.

If you scope your class to div.wpcf7 and add a margin: 0 auto there instead, that will cascade as expected and horizontally center your form for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am unable to apply anything to this class. If I set the scope to div.wpcf, nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading the [Contact Form 7 style plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-style/). It wraps the form with additionnal classes which makes customization easy.